# Events not saving through my modal on FullCalendar (bs4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, twitter-bootstrap-4

I've been working on my own first independent project on fullcalendar, but I'm having issues adding and saving events through my modal. I've followed tutorials and code from similar issues but it's not working. Any ideas?

I want to be able to add events with the modal, pick the time and save the event.

Thanks in advance

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar')
         .fullCalendar({
             allDaySlot: false,
             customButtons: {
                 reload: {
                     text: '+1 Year',
                     click: function() {
                         $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)));
                     }
                 }         
             },  
             themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
             defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
       nowIndicator: true,
         navLinks: true,
              allDaySlot: true,
         popupBreakPoint:786,
              selectable: true,
              selectHelper: true,
              droppable: true,
              slotDuration: '00:15:00',
              selectOverlap: false,
     editable: true,
     disableResizing: false,
             header: {
                 left: 'prev,next,today, reload, mnth',
                 center: 'title',
                 right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
             },
         select: function(start, end) {
                // Display the modal.
                // You could fill in the start and end fields based on the parameters
                $('.modal').modal('show');

            },
            eventClick: function(event, element) {
                // Display the modal and set the values to the event values.
                $('.modal').modal('show');
                $('.modal').find('#title').val(event.title);
                $('.modal').find('#starts-at').val(event.start);
                $('.modal').find('#ends-at').val(event.end);

            },
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true // allow "more" link when too many events

        });

        // Bind the dates to datetimepicker.
        // You should pass the options you need
        $("#starts-at, #ends-at").datetimepicker();

        // Whenever the user clicks on the "save" button om the dialog
        $('#save-event').on('click', function() {
            var title = $('#title').val();
            if (title) {
                var eventData = {
                    title: title,
                    start: $('#starts-at').val(),
                    end: $('#ends-at').val()
                };
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');

            // Clear modal inputs
            $('.modal').find('input').val('');

            // hide modal
            $('.modal').modal('hide');
         });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" />

<div id="calendar"></div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <form>
        <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="company">Client Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Clients name">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="vat">Starting time</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="starts-at" placeholder="starts-at">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="street">Ending time</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ends-at" placeholder="ends-at">
                  </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-event">Book</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Anyone? Still stuck after two days :/...

Comment: have you verified that the renderEvent method is definitely executing? And what does `eventData` look like at that moment? (Hint, log it to your console as JSON, or use your debugger). In particular, what exact string values are you entering for the dates? Only certain formats are accepted, unless you use momentJS to parse them first, which you aren't doing.